# Can a "staff arcane focus" also act like a Quarterstaff?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, spellcasting-focus

### Can I use a Quarterstaff as an Arcane Focus (Staff)?

In my opinion it would make sense.

They both even have the same weight!

The reason I'm asking this is because I'm making a wizard and it would be awesome if the answer to this question is yes!